# Flink keyby/window operator task execution place and internals

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new big for Flink. I am writing a simple Flink POC program, where I am able to get expected output. But I am not able to get the internals about the key by and window operation. Following is my code,

```
environment
.addSource(consumer)
.name("MyKafkaSource")
.setParallelism(2)
.flatMap(pojoMapper)
.name("MyPojoMapper")
.setParallelism(2)
.keyBy(new MyKeyExtractor())
.timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
.apply(new SumFunction())
.name("MySumFunction")
.setParallelism(2)
.print()
.name("S3FileSink")
.setParallelism(2)
```

While deploying the Flink job I get the following graph in Flink UI,

[Task Visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zAXo.png)

From the above image I understood it totally it uses 2 tasks and 4 slots, each task with 2 parallelism. First task has source, pojo mapper second task has sum function, sink function.

Now the question are,

1. Where does the KeyBy and Window operation lives? In first task or
   second task? Why it is not visible in above image? Is there is any
   way to visualise that?
2. Let's say for 1 window (60 sec interval), I receive 100 distinct
   keys and each key receives 5 records for 1 minute, so how many window
   objects are created internally for 1 window interval? I am assuming
   that 100 window objects are created and each window object will hold 5
   records. Whether my assumption are correct or not? If not could any
   one please explain what happens internally? Also if possible please
   share any documents related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are connected by data forwarding connections, the source and flatmap operators are chained together into the same task, and the same applies to the window and sink. But since the flatmap and window are connected by a keyBy, a network shuffle is needed there.

Thus your job has a total of 4 tasks: 2 instances of source plus flatmap, and 2 instances of window plus sink. These 4 tasks are deployed into 2 task slots, each of which has a source/flatmap task, and a window/sink task.

keyBy is depicted where it says HASH on the diagram. keyBy isn't an operator, but is instead a description of how the operators before and after the keyBy are connected.

These two lines of code

```
.timeWindow(Time.seconds(60))
.apply(new SumFunction())
```

together describe the window operator, which is shown on the diagram as `mySumFunction`. The window is in the second task.

You are correct in assuming that there is a window for each distinct key, and each of those 100 windows contains 5 records.

For resources for learning more about Flink, I can recommend [the Apache Flink Training](https://training.ververica.com/), [Stream Processing with Apache Flink](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/149197429X), and searching for Flink Forward talks on YouTube.

Comment: So technically Key by operation happens at first task, based on the hash result either it forwards the stream to second task first parallelism or second task second parallelism right?

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is much more clear than the Flink documentation :). I don't have enough reputation to upvote it but I accepted the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually working on rewriting the intro documentation. Wish me luck.

Comment: ha ha. May the force be with you!